# Show $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1} \, dx=\frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\ln^22$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Tried to evaluate the integral

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1} \, dx$$
and managed to show that

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1} \, dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+x^2} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1+i)(x+1-i)} \, dx 
 + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1+ix )(x+1-ix )} \, dx\\ 
 &= -2\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1+i}2\right)
 -2\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3(-1-i)
\end{align}

which is equal to $ \frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\ln^22$.

It is perhaps unnecessary, though, to resort to evaluation in complex space. I would like to work out an elementary derivation of this integral result.

Comment: Proper usage in MathJax and LaTeX is `\operatorname{Im}` and `\operatorname{Li}`, not `\text{Im}` and `\text{Li}`. The former results in context-dependent spacing, so you don't need to manually add spacing as you did here. Note that in $\operatorname{Li}(1)$ and $\operatorname{Li} 1,$ the spaces to the right of $\operatorname{Li}$ differ from each other without any manual adjustments. In actual LaTeX, as opposed to MathJax, which is used here, you can put `\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}` before `\begin{document}` and then just type `\Li` in each instance. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the tip; I knew there was something like that but couldn't remember exactly.

Comment: Sometimes, an elementary derivation is not clearly seen at first sight or it doesn't exist at all. Mathematicians don't have an "elementary derivation" definition YET !!!.

Comment: @FelixMarin - it is true that unknown elementary derivation exists for some clean-looking integrals; but they are in the minority. I’d like to give this one a chance since it may not have been looked at before.

Comment: @Quanto I always try to find the simplest one. Sometimes it involves several attempts to find the right way. It’s a good exercise which leaves an enhancing of your training. Thanks..

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution based on real methods. Note that $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}=\frac{x^2-2x+2}{x^4+4}$. Then

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1}dx \\
= & \int_0^\infty {\frac{x^2\ln^2x }{x^4+4}}\overset{x^2=1/t^2}{dx}
-2\int_0^\infty {\frac{x\ln^2x }{x^4+4}} \overset{x^2=2t}{dx} 
 + 2\int_0^\infty { \frac{\ln^2x }{x^4+4} } \overset{x^2=2t^2}{dx} \\
= &
-\frac18\ln^22\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^2+1}dt
 -\frac18\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2t}{t^2+1}dt \\
& +\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \ln^22  \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^4+1}dt
 + \sqrt2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 t}{t^4+1}dt \\
= & 
-\frac{\ln^22}8\left(\frac\pi2\right)
 -\frac18\left(\frac{\pi^3}8\right) +\frac{\ln^22 }{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\right)
 + \sqrt2 \left(\frac{3\pi^3\sqrt2}{64}\right) \\
=& \frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\ln^22
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-a}}{x^2+2x+2}dx\overset{x\to 1/x}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{2x^2+2x+1}dx$$

$$=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+i)x^a}{1+(1+i)x}dx\overset{(1+i)x=u}{=}\Im \frac{1}{(1+i)^a}\int_0^\infty\frac{u^a}{1+u}du$$

$$=-\Im\frac{\pi\csc(a\pi)}{(1+i)^a}=2^{-a/2}\csc(a\pi)\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}a),$$

and your integral is $I''(0).$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

With $\ds{r \equiv -1 + \ic = \root{2}\expo{-\ic\pi/4}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{x + 1}^{2} + 1}\,\dd x} =
\left.\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\nu - 1} \over
\pars{x - r}\pars{x - \overline{r}}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ = 1^{\large -}}
\\[5mm] = &
\left.\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\nu - 1}\pars{%
{1 \over r - x} - {1 \over \overline{r} - x}}
{1 \over \overline{r} - r}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ = 1^{\large -}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\left.\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{\nu - 1} \over r - x}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ = 1^{\large -}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\Im\pars{{1 \over r}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{\pars{\color{red}{\nu} - 1}} \over 1 - x/r}\,\dd x}
_{\ \nu\ = 1^{\large -}}
\end{align}

---

Note that
$\ds{{1 \over 1 - x/r} = 
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{x \over r}^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\expo{\ic\pi k}\Gamma\pars{1 + k} \over r^{k}}{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$

---

With [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem);
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{x + 1}^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &
-\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\Im\bracks{{1 \over r}\,
\Gamma\pars{\nu}\,{\expo{-\ic \pi\nu}\,\,\Gamma\pars{1 - \nu} \over r^{-\nu}}}_{\ \nu\ = 1^{\large -}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\Im\braces{\pars{-r}^{\nu - 1}\,
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\nu}\Gamma\pars{1 - \nu}}}
_{\ \nu\ = 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\Im\bracks{%
\pars{1 - \ic}^{\nu - 1}\,
{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\nu}}}_{\ \nu\ = 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\bracks{2^{\nu/2 - 1/2}\,\,\sin\pars{\bracks{1 - \nu}\,{\pi \over 4}}
\csc\pars{\pi\nu}}_{\ \nu\ = 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{5\pi^{3} \over 64} + {\pi \over 16}\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\approx 2.5167
\\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

We can use the integral of
\begin{equation}
  f(z)=\frac{\ln^3z}{(z+1)^2+2}
 \end{equation}
along the classical keehole contour: above the positive real axis , along the large circle, back from below along the positive axis and avoiding the origin by a small circle. Except the horizontal parts, the other contributions can be shown to vanish. Above the axis, $z=x+i0^+$ and $\ln^3(z)=\ln^3(x)$, while below, $z=x+i0^-$ and $\ln^3(z)=(\ln(x)+2i\pi)^3$. The integral can then be written as
\begin{align}
  J&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{(x+1)^2+1}dx-\int_0^\infty\frac{(\ln(x)+2i\pi)^3}{(x+1)^2+1}dx
 \end{align}
Considering the imaginary part of the integral,
\begin{align}
 \Im J&=-3 \left( 2\pi \right)\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1}dx+\left( 2\pi \right)^3\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}dx\\
 \Im J&=-6\pi I+2\pi^4
\end{align}
The poles of the function are $z_{\pm}=-1\pm i$, or $z_+=\sqrt{2}e^{i3\pi/4},z_-=\sqrt{2}e^{i5\pi/4}$. Corresponding residues $R_\pm=\ln^3(z_\pm)/\left( 2(1+z_\pm) \right)$, we deduce
\begin{equation}
 J=2i\pi\left[\frac{\left( \ln\sqrt{2} +3i\pi/4\right)^3}{2i}-\frac{\left( \ln\sqrt{2} +5i\pi/4\right)^3}{2i}\right]
\end{equation}
Then,
$$\Im J=\frac{49\pi^4}{32}-\frac{3\pi^2}{8}$$
Finally,
\begin{equation}
 I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1} \, dx = \frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\ln^22
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(x+1)^2+1} \, dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{x^2+2x+2} \, dx\\
&\overset{x=\sqrt{2}t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(\sqrt{2}t)}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1} \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(\sqrt{2})}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1} \, dt}_{=\dfrac{\pi\ln^2 2}{8\sqrt{2}}}+\underbrace{\sqrt{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(\sqrt{2})\ln t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1} \, dt}_{=0}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1} \, dt\\
&=\dfrac{\pi\ln^2 2}{16}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1} \, dt\\
K&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 (tx)}{(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)} \, dt\,dx\\
&\overset{u(x)=tx}=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln^2 u}{(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1)(u^2+\sqrt{2}tu+t^2)} \, dt\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \ln^2 u\left[\frac{(u+1)\ln\left(\frac{t^2+\sqrt{2}tu+u^2}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1}\right)}{2(1-u)(1+u^2)}-\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{u+\sqrt{2}t}{u}\right)}{1+u^2}-\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}t+1\right)}{1+u^2}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \ln^2 u\left(-\frac{\pi}{1+u^2}-\frac{(1+u)\ln u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}+\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{1+u^2}\right) du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+u)\ln^3 u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-\int_0^1\frac{(1+u)\ln^3 u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}du-\int_1^\infty\frac{(1+v)\ln^3 v}{(1-v)(1+v^2)}dv\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1}{v}}=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-\int_0^1\frac{(1+u)\ln^3 u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}du-\int_0^1\frac{(1+u)\ln^3 u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-2\int_0^1\frac{(1+u)\ln^3 u}{(1-u)(1+u^2)}du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\int_0^1 \frac{2v\ln^3 v}{1+v^2}dv\\
&\overset{u=v^2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1+u}du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\frac{1}{8}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\int_0^1 \frac{2v\ln^3 v}{1-v^2}dv\right)\\
&\overset{u=v^2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\frac{1}{8}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)\\
&==-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u^2}du-\frac{135}{64}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\times \frac{\pi^3}{8}-\frac{135}{64}\times -\frac{\pi^4}{15}\\
&=\frac{5\pi^4}{64}
\end{align}

On the other hand,
\begin{align}K&=2\underbrace{\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}\right)^2}_{=0}+2\sqrt{2}\left(J-\frac{\pi\ln^2 2}{16}\right)\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}dx}_{=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}}\end{align}

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \boxed{J=\frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac{\pi\ln^2 2}{16}}$

NB:
I assume that,

\begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}dx&=\frac{\pi^3}{8}\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx&=-6\zeta(4)\\
\displaystyle\zeta(4)&=\frac{\pi^4}{90}\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad if you write
$$(x+1)^2+1=(x-a)(x-b)$$
$$\frac 1{(x+1)^2+1}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac 1{x-a}-\frac 1{x-b} \right)$$ making that you face two integrals
$$I_c=\int \frac {\log^2(x)}{x-c}\,dx=\log ^2(x) \log (x-c)-2\int \frac{ \log (x) \log (x-c)}{x}\,dx$$
$$I_c=-2 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)+2 \log (x)
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)+\log ^2(x) \log \left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)$$